# Facebook to check "like" on fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I noted there is a link to generate "like button" code at :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

However it wasn't act as the top of fanpage "like" button which will redirect users to another page if I setup to check the pages liked or not. Is there any other way that I can generate the button as the top of fanpage "like button" behavior or way of using the recent plugins like and redirect users once they liked the page?

Eric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a XFBML like button then you can use the JavaScript SDK to detect likes by subcribing to the `edge.create` event using [FB.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        // Do redirect here
    }
);
```

For more information on the Facebook JavaScript SDK please go here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/